# How to map the iterator value to sink in adf

Tags: azure-data-factory

A question concerning Azure Data Factory.

I need to persist the iterator value from a lookup activity (an Id column from a sql table) to my sink together with other values.

How to do that?

I thought that I could just reference the iterator value as @{item().id} as source and a destination column name from from my sql table sink. That doesn’t seems to work. The resulting value in the destination column is NULL.

Answer (score 0):

- I have used 2 look up activities, one for id values and the other for remaining values. Now, to combine and insert these values to sink table, I have used the following:
- The ids look up activity output is as following:

[image]

- I have one more column to combine with above id values. The following is the look up output for that:

[image]

- I have given the following dynamic content as the items value in for each as following:

```
@range(0,length(activity('ids').output.value))
```

[image]

- Inside for each activity, I have given the following script activity query to insert data as required into sink table:

```
insert into t1 values(@{activity('ids').output.value[item()].id},'@{activity('remaining rows').output.value[item()].gname}')
```

- The data would be inserted successfully and the following is the reference image of the same:

[image]